# Thumbnails to open in a new div (not lightbox)

Tags: html, css

I have a rectangle on top and a set of thumbnails below. I need to write code so that when I click on a thumbnail, the image enlarges to open in that upper rectangle space (not using Lightbox). How do I confine the image to that upper rectangle? Is there a way to specify the target as being that box? Or do you use an iframe? If so, how do iframes work?

Comment: Don't use an iframe. It sounds like you could do this with just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JavaScript
Hope this helps

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function f(imageSource){
     document.getElementById("enlargedImage").src=imageSource;
}
</script>

<table width="585" height="482" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="50" bgcolor="#000000">
<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="600" height="326">
<img src="images/gallery/img1.jpg" name="enlargedImage" id="enlargedImage" width="492" height="287" /></td></tr>

<tr><td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" colspan="2">

<img src="images/gallery/img1.jpg" name="d" id="d" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img1.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />
<img src="images/gallery/img2.jpg" name="d" id="d2" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img2.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />
<img src="images/gallery/img3.jpg" name="d" id="d2" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img3.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />
<img src="images/gallery/img4.jpg" name="d" id="d2" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img4.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />
<img src="images/gallery/img5.jpg" name="d" id="d2" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img5.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />
<img src="images/gallery/img6.jpg" name="d" id="d2" onmouseover="f('images/gallery/img6.jpg')" width="70" height="50" />

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link which might solve your problem. http://html5box.com/html5gallery/index.php